# How to check for a file in FTP server location and send the same file from FTP location through mail

Tags: oracle, plsql, ftp

A text file is being created in FTP Server when an interface runs,

I need to check whether the created have any records,if it has values then i must be sending the same text file through mail using PL/SQL.

Thanks a million in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

there exists a great ftp packages build by Tim Hall.
http://www.oracle-base.com/dba/scripts.php
-> Miscellaneous -> ftp.pkb and ftp.pks

For the email issue you can use the Oracle package UTL_MAIL.

You need a job which execute the search on the FTP server in order to find the text file.

I like to have loggings, so my prefered way of you task would be:
1) Read the ftp directory nd search for the text file
2) Store the text file name, content and sysdate in a table
3) Delete/rename the file from the ftp server, so you would not load it again
4) Check if the content is not null (from the table)
5) If it is not null send the email
6) Mark the data row in the table, that it was checked

Hope it helps.

brgds,
Birthe